# How do I install SSSD on Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, ldap, centos

I want to do LDAP authentication on my Amazon Linux server.

The CentOS howtos say to

```
yum install sssd
```

But that gives:

```
No package sssd available.
```

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Linux is not Centos, it doesn't use the same repositories. Generally, Amazon Linux is mostly compatible with Redhat/Centos repositories. But you may run into dependency issues.